# How to "normalize" time in a variable to start at 0 by a Variable with multiple levels (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe with multiple batches (these are in a variable called BatchID) and there's a time column. These batches are at multiple different time frames and so don't overlay well.  Here is a subset of the data:

```
BatchID DateTime    H2 Inlet Flow
R73142  10/19/2016 2:43 29.257
R73142  10/19/2016 2:43 29.257
R73142  10/19/2016 2:44 29.235
R73142  10/19/2016 2:44 29.235
R73142  10/19/2016 2:45 29.212
R73138  10/12/2016 1:48 14.821
R73138  10/12/2016 1:48 14.821
R73138  10/12/2016 1:49 13.421
R73138  10/12/2016 1:49 13.421
R73138  10/12/2016 1:50 14.62
R73138  10/12/2016 1:50 14.62 
R73138  10/12/2016 1:51 14.289
R73138  10/12/2016 1:51 14.289
R73138  10/12/2016 1:52 15.087
R73138  10/12/2016 1:52 15.087
R73138  10/12/2016 1:53 14.712
R89556  11/1/2016 8:40  -0.026
R89556  11/1/2016 8:40  -0.026
R89556  11/1/2016 8:41  24.158
R89556  11/1/2016 8:41  24.158
R89556  11/1/2016 8:42  22.828
R89556  11/1/2016 8:42  22.828
R89556  11/1/2016 8:43  21.272
R89556  11/1/2016 8:43  21.272
```

I hope that reads well.

I want to do two things with this data (and my data is much larger than the example):

1. Set the 1st time point at each batch to be at 0 mins and then the next time points to be the time difference from zero for every BatchID. This will allow me to overlay and visualize the data better
2. Because I know the spacing between each point is acquired at the same time, I would like to do - for each BatchID - make a sequence of integers from 0 to the nrow() for each BatchID. i.e. in my example data, batchID R73142 is 5 rows so I'd like a variable that is 1:5, then for R73138 it would be 1:11. I know I'd like to use seq(), I just don't know how to do this in this example.

I know how to do both of these but not in this dataframe with multiple batches (i.e. a Unique ID).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ave` like this.  The question says the numbers should start from 0 but then discusses 1:11.  Below they start from 0 but if you want them to start from 1 then omit the -1.

```
DF <- data.frame(BatchID = c("A", "A", "B"), Flow = c(1.1, 2.1, 3.1)) # test data
transform(DF, Seq = ave(Flow, BatchID, FUN = seq_along) - 1)
```

giving:

```
  BatchID Flow Seq
1       A  1.1   0
2       A  2.1   1
3       B  3.1   0
```